# In R, how do I subset a data.frame by values from another data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have two data frames.  The first, `df.1`, contains two columns of paired numerical identifiers, where each column includes ~100,000 rows.  The second  data frame, `df.2`, includes one column (`df.2$C`) of numerical identifiers. This data frame has around 200 rows.

How can I find the paired subset of data of `df.1` that includes only the rows with values of the identifiers found in `df.2$C`?

The final subset would include the paired data of `df.1` which corresponds to identifiers found in `df.2$C` that match the identifiers found in `df.1$A`, `df.1$B` or both.

Answer (score 15):

You could use `?"%in%"` (similar to `?match`):

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=sample(1:10, 10), B=sample(1:10, 10))
df2 <- data.frame(C=1:5)

selectedRows <- (df1$A %in% df2$C | df1$B %in% df2$C)

dfReduced <- df1[selectedRows,]
```